# What are the best reusable django apps for form processing?

Tags: python, django, windows, pinax

In my application I want to process some form data and show it later on a different page.

My question is: Can you recommend any django apps to quickly set up such a system?

I appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Have you tried the built-in [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/) and did you run into an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like django-crispy-forms ?
https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms

which is built on top of the already capable django forms framework - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Django cripsy forms helps you organize your form layout and configuration in `forms.py`, so keeping your template `{{ form }}` context variable simple and concise; without loosing customizability in your `forms.py` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can work with generic views in django which are suitable for general functionality.

Reference for [generic form based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/), more on [class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)

For rendering may be you can use [twitter bootstrap CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or as @Calvin Cheng mentioned [django-crispy forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms).

Answer (score 2):

Django allows you to do this super easily without any apps. I'd highly recommend you read up on its basic form processing features.